# Unconstrained optimization: Derivative of FOC w.r.t parameter is 0?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, optimization

Suppose we have an unconstrained optimization problem
$$ \max f(x)$$

and suppose there is some constant (i.e. a parameter), $c$ in $f(x)$.

The FOC of the optimization problem is $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$$

If we take the total derivative of the FOC with respect to the parameter,$c$ is this total derivative equal to 0?

---

let me try stating what I think is an equivalent (or more rigorous) statement of the question:

- Let $x^*(c)$ denote the solution to the unconstrained optimization, where $x$ depends on some parameter in $f$
- then by definition we have $$\tag{EQ1} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\vert_{x=x^*(c)}=0$$ for every $c$.
- **Is it then correct to say that the total derivative of the left hand side of (EQ1), with respect to $c$, is $=0$?**

I believe my confusion is arising from the fact that, typically, if we say a function $g(y)=0$, we can't say that $g'(y)=0$, but with (EQ1) we know that the equation holds at every $x^*(c)$ (i think this might be called an identity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are obviously many regularity issues here. Let us take $f : (c,x) \mapsto f(c,x)$ is say $C^2$ on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^d$ and assume that, for every $c \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a unique maximizer $x^*(c)$ of $f(c, \cdot)$. Assume moreover that $c \mapsto x^*(c)$ is $C^1$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Then, for every $c \in \mathbb{R}$, you indeed have
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (c,x^*(c)) = 0
$$
which is an identity of which you can indeed take the total derivative with respect to $c$, yielding
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial c \partial x} (c,x^*(c))
+ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} (c,x^*(c)) \frac{\partial x^*}{\partial c}(c) = 0.
$$
Here I assumed that everything was legitimate. The main difficulty is probably to check that, in your particular case, the minimizer is indeed unique, $f$ is indeed $C^2$, and $c \mapsto x^*(c)$ is also $C^1$.

Comment: Thank you. This answer is very clear and detailed. The continuity requirements I believe as so that the derivatives exist, but why does the maximizer need to be unique? Is it so the function is well defined?

Comment: Well, if you have multiple maximizers, say a set $\mathcal{X}(c)$, then you need to find a *selection* $x^*(c) \in \mathcal{X}(c)$ which has $C^1$ regularity. For this selected maximizer, the same reasoning applies. I stated it with a unique one for clarity. If you have multiple ones, constructing a selection is not always easy.